# Aggregating table data in MySQL, is there an easier way to do this?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a query that aggregates data from a table.

Essentially I have a long list of devices that have been inventoried and eventually installed over the last couple of years.

I want to find the average amount of time between when the device was received and when it was installed, and then have that data sorted by the month the device was installed. BUT in each month's row, I also want to include the data from the previous months.

So essentially what I want to see is: (sorry for terrible formatting)

```
MonthInstalled   | TimeToInstall | Total#Devices
-----------------+---------------+----------------------------
Jan              | 10 Days       | 5
Feb(=Jan+Feb)    | 15 Days       | 18 (5 in Jan + 13 in Feb)    
Mar(=Jan+Feb+Mar)| 13 Days       | 25 (5 + 13 + 7)

...
```

The query I currently have written looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO DevicesInstall
SELECT ROUND(AVG(DATEDIFF(dvc.dt_install , dvc.dt_receive)), 1) AS 'Install', 
  COUNT(dvc.dvc_model) AS 'Total Devices', 
  MAX(dvc.dt_install) AS 'Date', 
  loc.loc_campus AS 'Campus' 
FROM dvc_info dvc, location loc 
WHERE dvc.dvc_loc_bin = loc.loc_bin 
  AND dvc.dt_install < '20160201'
;
```

Although this is functional, I have to iterate this for each month manually, so it is not scale-able. Is there a way to condense this at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can return the dates using an inline view (derived table), and then join to the `dvc_info` table, so we can get the "cumulative" results.

To get the results for:

```
Jan
Jan+Feb
Jan+Feb+Mar
```

We need to return three copies of the rows for Jan, and two copies of the rows for Feb, and then collapse the those rows into an appropriate group.

The `loc_campus` is being included in the SELECT list... not clear why that is needed. If we want results "by campus", then we need to include that expression in the GROUP BY clause. Otherwise, the value returned for that non-aggregate is indeterminate... we will get a value for some row "in the group", but it could be any row.

Something like this:

```
SELECT d.dt                                                  AS `before_date`
     , loc.loc_campus                                        AS `Campus`
     , ROUND(AVG(DATEDIFF(dvc.dt_install,dvc.dt_receive)),1) AS `Install`
     , COUNT(dvc.dvc_model)                                  AS `Total Devices`
     , MAX(dvc.dt_install)                                   AS `latest_dt_install`
  FROM ( SELECT           '2016-01-01' + INTERVAL  1 MONTH AS dt
         UNION ALL SELECT '2016-01-01' + INTERVAL  2 MONTH
         UNION ALL SELECT '2016-01-01' + INTERVAL  3 MONTH
         UNION ALL SELECT '2016-01-01' + INTERVAL  4 MONTH
         UNION ALL SELECT '2016-01-01' + INTERVAL  5 MONTH
         UNION ALL SELECT '2016-01-01' + INTERVAL  6 MONTH
         UNION ALL SELECT '2016-01-01' + INTERVAL  7 MONTH
         UNION ALL SELECT '2016-01-01' + INTERVAL  8 MONTH
         UNION ALL SELECT '2016-01-01' + INTERVAL  9 MONTH
         UNION ALL SELECT '2016-01-01' + INTERVAL 10 MONTH
         UNION ALL SELECT '2016-01-01' + INTERVAL 11 MONTH
         UNION ALL SELECT '2016-01-01' + INTERVAL 12 MONTH
       ) d
 CROSS
  JOIN location loc
  LEFT     
  JOIN dvc_info dvc
    ON dvc.dvc_loc_bin = loc.loc_bin
   AND dvc.dt_install  < d.dt
 GROUP
    BY d.dt
     , loc.loc_campus
 ORDER
    BY d.dt
     , loc.loc_campus
```

Note that the value returned for `d.dt` will be the "up until" date. We're going to get '2016-02-01' returned for the January results. If we want to return a value of January date, we can use an expression in the SELECT list...

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(d.dt + INTERVAL -1 MONTH,'%Y-%m')    AS `month`
```

Lots of options on query alternatives.

But it looks like the "big hump" is that to get cumulative results, we need to return multiple copies of the `dvc_info` rows, so the rows can be collapsed into each "grouping".

I recommend working on just the `SELECT` first. And get that tested working, before monkeying around to turn it into an `INSERT ... SELECT`.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

We can use any query as an inline view (derived table `d`) that returns a set of dates we want.

e.g.

```
  FROM ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(m.install_dt,'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH AS dt
           FROM dvc_install m
          WHERE m.install_dt >= '2016-01-01'
          GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(m.install_dt,'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
       ) d
```

Note that with this approach, if there are no `install_dt` in February, we won't get back a row for February. Using the static `UNION ALL SELECT` approach allows us to get back "zero" counts, i.e. to return rows for months where there isn't an install_dt in that month. (But that's the answer to a different question... how do I get back a "zero" count for February when there aren't any rows for Februrary?)

Alternatively, if we have a calendar table e.g. `cal` that contains a list of the dates we want, we could just reference the table in place of the inline view, or the inline view query could get rows from that.

```
  FROM ( SELECT cal.dt
           FROM cal cal
          WHERE cal.dt >= '2016-01-01'
            AND cal.dt <= NOW()
            AND DATE_FORMAT(cal.dt,'%d') = '01'
       ) d
```

Comment: This definitely helps to condense the code, so thanks for that. But I think we still have the issue with scalability. If new entries were to be added to the database for a new month, another line of the 'UNION ALL SELECT' would need to be added to compensate. Is there a way that we can iterate that statement automatically?

Comment: @BradQuinn:  we could use any query that returns a set of dates, rather than a UNION ALL list. Using that `UNION ALL SELECT` we can get aggregates that include "zero" counts... but that's the answer to a different question... how to get a result for Feb when there were no install_dt in February. `FROM ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(m.install_dt,'%Y-%m-01')+INTERVAL 1 MONTH FROM dvc_info m WHERE m.install_dt >= '2016-01-01' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(m.install_dt,'%Y-%m-01')+INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) d`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking to do, thanks a ton!